# Modify the order array when using sortable() (jqueryUI)

Tags: jquery

I have a list I would sort thanks to the sortable fonction of jQueryUI:

```
    <ul id="list-cat">
        <li id="cat_0" >Coach</li>
        <li id="cat_1" >Victory</li>
        <li id="cat_2" >Defeat</li> 
    </ul>
```

My script:

```
    $("#list-cat").sortable({ 
        placeholder: 'highlight',
        update: function() {  
            var order = $('#list-cat').sortable('serialize');           
            $.post("my url...",order); 
            alert(order);   // displays for example "cat[]=1&cat[]=0&cat[]=2"
        }
      });
```

My url receives a $_POST['cat'] array with the $order as key and the $id_cat as value. I need to have the li value (Coach, Victory, etc) as array value instead of the $id_cat, is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ids to be `cat_Coach`, `cat_Victory`, etc.

See the [jQuery UI docs on `.sortable("serialize")`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize):

> Serializes the sortable's item id's into a form/ajax submittable string. Calling this method produces a hash that can be appended to any url to easily submit a new item order back to the server.
>
> It works by default by looking at the id of each item in the format 'setname_number', and it spits out a hash like "setname[]=number&setname[]=number".
>
> You can also give in a option hash as second argument to custom define how the function works. The possible options are: 'key' (replaces part1[] with whatever you want), 'attribute' (test another attribute than 'id') and 'expression' (use your own regexp).
>
> If serialize returns an empty string, make sure the id attributes include an underscore. They must be in the form: "set_number" For example, a 3 element list with id attributes foo_1, foo_5, foo_2 will serialize to foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2. You can use an underscore, equal sign or hyphen to separate the set and number. For example foo=1 or foo-1 or foo_1 all serialize to foo[]=1.